# In Linux Shell, how to find out which commands I use most often and how often?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, command-line

I want to find out which are the top 5 commands that I ran in the shell. I want to see which commands I use most often. It would be great if I can also see how often I ran these top commands.

Is there an easy way to find it without installing any plugins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using history command and combine it with `head -n` to get the top n commands.

To get the top 5 commands:

`history | awk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -5`

Result:

```
69 cd
66 ls
41 vi
40 git
24 rm
```

This means I have used `cd` most often, and I have used it 69 times.